# Intermittent issue with Logitech Webcam C270 on Pop OS 22.04 - UVC Camera (046d:0825)

Tags: linux-mint, camera, pop-os

I seem to have issues with my webcam on Pop OS 22.04 and on LMDE 4. I was using the same device flawlessly on Xubuntu 18.04.

When trying to use the camera with `cheese` or `guvcview` I often get a white screen but eventually get the expected image. Audio captured seem to work but it's apparently affecting video calls on Google Meet. I noticed the audio reception is choppy and there's no evidence of internet connectivity issue.

**Debug info:**

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:28ae Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Laptop Integrated Webcam HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f3:0210 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Glide
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
UVC Camera (046d:0825) (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/media0

Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate (usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media1

$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2+USB Mouse                            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UVC Camera (046d:0825)                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

When I plug the device on a USB port:

```
Jun 17 11:22:11 pop-os kernel: usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0825, bcdDevice= 0.12
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=2
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os kernel: usb 2-1: SerialNumber: BD107460
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os kernel: usb 2-1: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os kernel: input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input24
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os kernel: usb 2-1: set resolution quirk: cval->res = 384
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os mtp-probe[63240]: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1"
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os mtp-probe[63240]: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device UVC Camera (046d:0825) (/dev/input/event18)
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (**) UVC Camera (046d:0825): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'UVC Camera (046d:0825)'
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82 fd 107 paused 0
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (**) UVC Camera (046d:0825): always reports core events
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) event18 - UVC Camera (046d:0825): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) event18 - UVC Camera (046d:0825): device is a keyboard
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) event18 - UVC Camera (046d:0825): device removed
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input24/event18"
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "UVC Camera (046d:0825)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) event18 - UVC Camera (046d:0825): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2321]: (II) event18 - UVC Camera (046d:0825): device is a keyboard
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os mtp-probe[63265]: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1"
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os mtp-probe[63265]: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Jun 17 11:22:12 pop-os gnome-shell[2492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 6f with keysym 6f (keycode 20).
```

Testing the device:

```
$ guvcview -d /dev/video0
GUVCVIEW: version 2.0.7
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
V4L2_CORE: (UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP) Error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:601:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
control[0]:(unknown - 0x6) 0x980001 'User Controls'
control[10]:(unknown - 0x6) 0x9a0001 'Camera Controls'
V4L2_CORE: Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
GUVCVIEW: error setting spin value
control id: 0x009a0902 failed to set (error -1)
GUVCVIEW: error setting spin value

$ cheese 

(cheese:63521): cheese-WARNING **: 11:24:05.261: A lot of buffers are being dropped.: ../libs/gst/base/gstbasesink.c(3143): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstViewfinderBin:vf-bin/ClutterGstVideoSink:cluttergstvideosink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
```

I also noticed these errors:

```
Jun 17 10:41:37 pop-os kernel: usb 2-1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 10 on unit 2: -32 (exp. 2).
Jun 17 11:24:02 pop-os kernel: usb 2-1: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
Jun 17 11:24:02 pop-os kernel: uvcvideo 2-1:1.0: reset_resume error -5
```

**Notes:**

- I can use the integrated webcam, no problem
- I can use the Webcam mic
- Gstreamer is installed
- ffmpeg is installed
- `ubuntu-restricted-extras` package is installed
- My user belongs to the `video` group
- I managed to use the camera once with Zoom and Google Meet. The problem is intermittent but seem it's failing the majority of times

Comment: Have you tried with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, which is between a version where is works and does not work. The problem is probably the hardware drivers in 22.04 and LMDE, and we can hope that the driver(s) will be upgraded soon, at least if there is feedback. So it might be a good idea to write a bug report ;-)

Comment: I have been testing this device on different linux kernel versions and confirmed it's a hardware failure case =/

After fighting with it and testing a few times on different systems including Ubuntu 22.04 and Xubuntu 18.04, I got to the conclusion the device broke. I tested another device, same model, and was able to confirm it works on my computer as is, on Pop OS 22.04; I still see the same (kernel) error messages but I get the image as expected.

I can only say it was a terribly misleading coincidence the device broke just after I upgrade the OS.

Thanks!